# Trying to install memcached error

Tags: centos

Getting following error when trying to install memcached php

```
 yum install php-pecl-memcache
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security, universal-hooks
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * EA4: 208.100.0.204
 * base: chicago.gaminghost.co
 * epel: mirror.unl.edu
 * extras: denver.gaminghost.co
 * remi: repo1.dal.innoscale.net
 * remi-safe: repo1.dal.innoscale.net
 * updates: mirror.sesp.northwestern.edu
remi                                                     | 2.9 kB     00:00
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-pecl-memcache.x86_64 0:3.0.8-2.el6.remi.5.4 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php(zend-abi) = 20100525-x86-64 for package: php-pecl-memcache-3.0.8-2.el6.remi.5.4.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php(api) = 20100412-x86-64 for package: php-pecl-memcache-3.0.8-2.el6.remi.5.4.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/pecl for package: php-pecl-memcache-3.0.8-2.el6.remi.5.4.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/pecl for package: php-pecl-memcache-3.0.8-2.el6.remi.5.4.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-pear.noarch 1:1.10.1-12.el6.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-xml for package: 1:php-pear-1.10.1-12.el6.remi.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-posix for package: 1:php-pear-1.10.1-12.el6.remi.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-cli for package: 1:php-pear-1.10.1-12.el6.remi.noarch
---> Package php-pecl-memcache.x86_64 0:3.0.8-2.el6.remi.5.4 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php(zend-abi) = 20100525-x86-64 for package: php-pecl-memcache-3.0.8-2.el6.remi.5.4.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php(api) = 20100412-x86-64 for package: php-pecl-memcache-3.0.8-2.el6.remi.5.4.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-cli.x86_64 0:5.4.45-13.el6.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.45-13.el6.remi for package: php-cli-5.4.45-13.el6.remi.x86_64
---> Package php-pecl-memcache.x86_64 0:3.0.8-2.el6.remi.5.4 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php(zend-abi) = 20100525-x86-64 for package: php-pecl-memcache-3.0.8-2.el6.remi.5.4.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php(api) = 20100412-x86-64 for package: php-pecl-memcache-3.0.8-2.el6.remi.5.4.x86_64
---> Package php-process.x86_64 0:5.4.45-13.el6.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.45-13.el6.remi for package: php-process-5.4.45-13.el6.remi.x86_64
---> Package php-xml.x86_64 0:5.4.45-13.el6.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.45-13.el6.remi for package: php-xml-5.4.45-13.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-xml-5.4.45-13.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.45-13.el6.remi
           Installed: php-common-5.5.38-7.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php55)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.5.38-7.el6.remi
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-47.el6.x86_64 (base)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-47.el6
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-48.el6_8.x86_64 (updates)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-48.el6_8
           Available: php-common-5.4.45-12.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.45-12.el6.remi
           Available: php-common-5.4.45-13.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.45-13.el6.remi
Error: Package: php-pecl-memcache-3.0.8-2.el6.remi.5.4.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: php(zend-abi) = 20100525-x86-64
           Installed: php-common-5.5.38-7.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php55)
               php(zend-abi) = 20121212-64
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-47.el6.x86_64 (base)
               php(zend-abi) = 20090626
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-48.el6_8.x86_64 (updates)
               php(zend-abi) = 20090626
           Available: php-common-5.4.45-12.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php(zend-abi) = 20100525-x86-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.45-13.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php(zend-abi) = 20100525-x86-64
Error: Package: php-pecl-memcache-3.0.8-2.el6.remi.5.4.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: php(api) = 20100412-x86-64
           Installed: php-common-5.5.38-7.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php55)
               php(api) = 20121113-64
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-47.el6.x86_64 (base)
               php(api) = 20090626
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-48.el6_8.x86_64 (updates)
               php(api) = 20090626
           Available: php-common-5.4.45-12.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php(api) = 20100412-x86-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.45-13.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php(api) = 20100412-x86-64
Error: Package: php-process-5.4.45-13.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.45-13.el6.remi
           Installed: php-common-5.5.38-7.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php55)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.5.38-7.el6.remi
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-47.el6.x86_64 (base)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-47.el6
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-48.el6_8.x86_64 (updates)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-48.el6_8
           Available: php-common-5.4.45-12.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.45-12.el6.remi
           Available: php-common-5.4.45-13.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.45-13.el6.remi
Error: Package: php-cli-5.4.45-13.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.45-13.el6.remi
           Installed: php-common-5.5.38-7.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php55)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.5.38-7.el6.remi
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-47.el6.x86_64 (base)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-47.el6
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-48.el6_8.x86_64 (updates)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-48.el6_8
           Available: php-common-5.4.45-12.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.45-12.el6.remi
           Available: php-common-5.4.45-13.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.45-13.el6.remi
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Running centos 6.8
php 5.6

---

Now getting following

Transaction Check Error:
  file /usr/bin/php from install of php-cli-5.5.38-7.el6.remi.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ea-php-cli-0.2.0-1.1.1.cpanel.x86_64

---

Still getting error

```
Error: Package: php-cli-5.4.45-13.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.45-13.el6.remi
           Installed: php-common-5.5.38-7.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php55)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.5.38-7.el6.remi
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-47.el6.x86_64 (base)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-47.el6
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-48.el6_8.x86_64 (updates)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-48.el6_8
           Available: php-common-5.4.45-12.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.45-12.el6.remi
           Available: php-common-5.4.45-13.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.45-13.el6.remi
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Comment: Stop doing everything, and go seek help on a cPanel-specific support forum. We cannot help you with cPanel servers. You are likely to damage your system if you follow advice given for normal servers.

Answer (score 2):

> Installed: php-common-5.5.38-7.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php55)

You have PHP 5.5 installed from "remi-php55" repository

So you need to pull extension from the same repository.

Simpler way is to enable it by default:

```
yum install yum-utils
yum-config-manager --enable remi-php55
yum install php-pecl-memcache
```

As explained in the [Wizard](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/) instructions.

Notice: PHP 5.5 is EOL since July 2016, so I heartily recommend you consider to update to a supported version (5.6+), so enabling remi-php56 repository.

Answer (score 0):

**Step #1: Install Memcached PHP Extension**

First, clean-up yum:

```
yum clean all
```

As a matter of best practice we’ll update our packages:

```
yum -y update
```

Then installing PHP Memcached extension and related packages is now as simple as running just one command::

```
yum -y install php-pecl-memcache
```

Step #2: Verify Installation
Restart memcached and httpd:

```
systemctl restart memcached
systemctl restart httpd
```

Use the following command to view information on the installed PHP modules:

```
php -m | grep memcache
```